# nginx redirect include subdomain, www and parameters

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain, url-parameters

I want to redirect with nginx from

```
www.anysubdomain.domain.com?parameters , anysubdomain.com?parameters
```

to

```
www.domain.com?parameteres&anysubdomain
```

anysubdomain or parameters are optional

I tried

```
server_name ~^(?<subdub>.*).\domain\.com$;
rewrite      ^ http://www.domain.com/?mode=$subdub permanent;
```

but it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<subdub>.+)\.domain\.com$;
```

This regex will match zero or one appearance of "www.".

Also you have a mistake in your regex of using ".\domain". It should be "\.domain".

I also replace

```
(?<subdub>.*)
```

by

```
(?<subdub>.+)
```

to make sure a non-empty subdomain name. This way the server_name won't match "www.domain.com" itself, which may cause a redirect loop.